# Using Swift Cocoapods in Objective-C project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Good day,

I am relatively new in Swift language. I have been using objective-c. 
Recently I tried adding a swift pods into my objective-c project but I get loads of errors that I know nothing of. I am attaching the screenshot. Can you please take a look and help me out with this. thankyou! 
[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **Tried adding a swift pods into my objective-c project**? Can you please be a little more specific?

Comment: Yes you can use Swift pods in an Obj-C project but you'll save yourself a lot of hassle if you stick to Obj-C pods. Check with the creator to see if if the pod is compatible with Obj-C project. Also perhaps you could list the offending pod here and someone could try it in their Obj-C project.